# Style part of ng-option text

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Need some help with styling an angularjs ng-option. 
I want it to look like this:[image]

So I have the ng-option like this.

```
<select ng-options="servicepoint.id as servicepoint.name+' '+servicepoint.routeDistance+' m' for servicepoint in $ctrl.servicepoints">
</select>
```

This result in this:

[image]

So do you guys know if I can style just the last part with the meters to a blue color and make an ellipse if text is to long. The distans should be visible all the time. 
It seems like `<option>` can't have `<span>`-tags or stuff like that so I can style the text?

I was trying to put the option out in an ng-repeat and style it there but no success.

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="service in $ctrl.servicepoints">
        <span>{{service.name}}</span><span style="color: blue">{{service.routeDistance}} m</span>
    </option>
</select>
```

Anyone that can guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Below code with ng-repeat should work, what went wrong?

Comment: @DanteTheSmith Nothing happens. Its just ignore the span-tags and no styling gets set. If I look in the chrome dev console it looks like this: `<option ng-repeat="service in $ctrl.servicepoints" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Coop Storgatan 959m</option>`

Comment: OOOF, just checked on something - An option element cannot have any child elements (in DOM only text node is allowed) This is the official HTML 5 spec. In your case, it has 2 child elements - spans. Seems the sec tries to keep options simple text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, here is a full response from what I gathered, I wish I found a simpler hack around it but these are the facts:

- **This element is rendered by the OS, not HTML**
- **It cannot be styled via CSS**.
- What is worse, **option element will not render any elements inside it**, the only text node is allowed to be a child of option element in DOM.

Solution:

There are replacement plug-ins that look like a  but are actually composed of regular HTML elements that CAN be styled. This is where you should begin your search.

For further explanation:
[this text](https://medium.com/@ross.angus/styleable-select-box-replacement-in-pure-css-and-semantic-html-1f38a400b285)

The text is decent I read through it, tackles the problem from discovery to solution phase.

Comment: Okey. Thats a bummer. Thanks for your answer and I will look int to your link. Thought this would be much more simple :P

Comment: Agreed, simpler but unfortunately it is not possible. Either you don't style it or you work around with custom html/css or include a package that already does that for you to make something appear as select when in fact it is not, then it can be styled just like any other styleable element.